# Cannot reduce RU on Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I need help to know why I can't adjust these down to 400 RU/s from 1000 RU/s:

[Azure Cosmos DB Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lt45.png)

When I set to Manual I also get this issue:

[Manual Provisioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGaZp.png)

What steps do I need to take to go down to 400 RU/s on this collection?

Thanks

I tried to reduce to 400 RU/s but it wouldn't accept the value, I want it to accept 400 RU/s

Comment: I've found that after changing from autoscale to manual you need to refresh the page so it refreshes the new limit. The min limit for autoscale max is 1000. When you change to manual  it can still remember this "1000" value until you reload the page

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshot you shared, I believe you have provisioned the container in `Autoscale` mode. In this mode, the minimum throughput for the container has to be 1000 RU/s based on the documentation provided [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits#minimum-throughput-limits).

[image]

**Update**

I think there is some discrepancy between how different blades work in Azure Portal. I am able to reproduce the behavior you are seeing if I try to change the throughput using either "Scale" or "Data Explorer". However I am able to reduce the throughput to 400 when I changed it through "Settings".

[image]

Comment: Hi Gaurav, when setting to Manual I still get the same error message unable to go below 1000 RU/s, please see my updated post with a new screenshot. Thanks for your help

Comment: Please see my updated answer. HTH.